# Sensor/transducer for low pressure gas measurement?

Tags: arduino, transducer

First time poster here so let me know if I'm missing key info.

I'm helping a friend create an Arduino-powered data collection system for his coffee roaster, and we'd like to track the natural gas pressure (in W.C.) being sent to the burners.

Can anyone recommend a low-cost solution for this?  I think we'd have to have a plumber install it, because it should be inserted into the pipe leading to the already-installed analog readout and allow us to push data to a microcontroller.  I don't know the exact diameter of the copper pipe but I think it's a standard size.  Even if someone could point me in the direction of the right class of device and/or a manufacturer, that would be great.

Thanks.

EDIT: The range we need is 0-16" W.C.  or 0-40 mbar

Comment: If "low cost" means something you build yourself I would stay away from that for obvious reasons. Just be safe try to find a real pressure transducer which is designed for that application. If you just want to compare the current pressure to a reference value an optical sensor over the analog gauge might work. But think about what happens if this setup fails.

Comment: I'm hadn't intended to build it myself, but that was before your suggestion of an optical sensor over the analog gauge. I don't however want to obscure the readout of the analog gauge with this solution, so I'm not sure that would be an optimal solution.  Interesting idea that I might still try out though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the plumbing/safety aspects, but I think you are probably looking for something like [this sensor from Honeywell](http://uk.farnell.com/honeywell-s-c/px2af1xx300psaax/pressure-transducer-300psi-1-4/dp/2080162)

[image: Pressure sensor]

The above came from Farnell, where there are [677 other options](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203233&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=203233&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203233&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=203233) to look at.
Many of the expensive ones are incorporated into some metal piping which I imagine can be inserted in between or on a tap off (depending on design), and some of the cheapest are nothing more than an IC with a small tube attached, but I'm not sure how you could use these safely.

I would ask your plumber about suitability before purchasing anything, you can download a copy of the datasheet for measurements/specs.
Digikey/Mouser/RS/etc are likely to have other options also.

Comment: This is on the right track Oli, thanks for the lead.  The form factor is exactly what I was picturing.  I think I need something that measures lower pressures though, since 1 PSI = 27.6 WCI (Water Column inches), and my range is 0-16 WCI.

Comment: Yes, most of the ones in that form factor seem to be quite high pressure ranges. There is [this one](http://uk.farnell.com/keller/pr21sr-80444-3-1/pressure-transducer-0-1bar-g/dp/7099460) that does 0-1 bar. You may have to look at using one of the little plastic IC type ones like [this](http://uk.farnell.com/honeywell-s-c/xpx01d/sensor-pressure-1-to-1psi/dp/1971753) - possibly fitted inside the end of a pipe.